# Confusing error in initializer list using std::move on unique_pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, unique-ptr, initializer, stdmove

I'm getting this error from this constructor

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   `(active) E0289   no instance of constructor "std::unique_ptr<_Ty,
>   _Dx>::unique_ptr [with _Ty=InputComponent, _Dx=std::default_delete<InputComponent>]" matches the argument list`

Code:

```
    class GameWorldObject 
    {
    public:

    GameWorldObject::GameWorldObject(std::unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> graphicsComponent, std::unique_ptr<LogicComponent> logicComponent, std::unique_ptr<InputComponent> inputComponent)
        :
        m_graphicsComponent( std::move(graphicsComponent) ), // ERROR
        m_inputComponent( std::move(logicComponent) ), // ERROR
        m_logicComponent( std::move(inputComponent) ) // ERROR
    {}



        // these auto initialize to null
        std::unique_ptr<GraphicsComponent> m_graphicsComponent;
        std::unique_ptr<LogicComponent> m_logicComponent;
        std::unique_ptr<InputComponent> m_inputComponent;

    };
```

I'm dumb stuck because this example works for me and seems identical to the previous:

```
    struct Animal {
        virtual ~Animal() {}
        virtual void speak() = 0;
    };


    struct Dog : Animal {
        void speak() override { std::cout << "Woof!\n"; }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Animal> createPet() {
        return std::make_unique<Dog>();

    }

    class House {
    public:
        House(std::unique_ptr<Animal> pet) // seems identical
            :
            m_pet(std::move(pet)) // seems identical
        {}

        std::unique_ptr<Animal> m_pet; // seems identical
    };

    void main()
    {

        auto pet = createPet(6.0);
        pet->speak();

        House house(std::move(pet));

        //pet->speak(); err pet is nullptr
        house.m_pet->speak();
    }
```

What the difference between these two?
Why is the top one not working?

Note I have not implemented any kind of constructor, destructor, or copy constructor in `InputComponent`, `GraphicsComponent`, or `LogicComponent`.

In fact, this is `InputComponent`

```
class InputComponent
{

};
```

Comment: `void main()` isn't valid in C++. It must always be `int main()` or `int main(int argc,char* argv[])` ?

Comment: "*Note I have not implemented any kind of constructor, destructor, or copy constructor*". What happens if you implement a constructor?

Comment: do you use forward declarations?

Comment: Turn on warnings.  Fix warnings.  Code compiles.  In `m_inputComponent( std::move(logicComponent) )` a logic component is not a input component.

Comment: @Eljay wow, I looked at this for over an hour... How do you "turn on warnings"? What did you mean by that?

Comment: For my platform, I turn on warnings by using `alias c17='/usr/bin/clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -std=c++17'`